# ComboBox Item is not loaded in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, combobox, wpf-controls

My combo box item is not showing. It is working fine on visual studio 2015 . But when I try this in visual studio 2013, it is showing nothing. I set debug point in ComboBox_Loaded function and from that, I have seen that the last 3 lines are skipped by the compiler. How can I solve it for Visual Studio 2013. Thanks in advance.

```
<Window x:Class="GraphicalUserInterface.ShowDataByObjectsWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ShowDataByObjectsWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="10">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Object Options"/>
        <ComboBox  x:Name="dbObjects" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class ShowDataByObjectsWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> dataTableName = new List<string>();
    public static string comboItem;

    public ShowDataByObjectsWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
    }

    private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataTableName.Add("adasd");
        dataTableName.Add("adaasdsd");


        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = dataTableName;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

        string value = comboBox.SelectedItem as string;
        this.Title = "Selected: " + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: "that I have seen that the last 3 lines are skipped by the compiler" : try to clean and force a rebuild of your project. It seems that you're running an oldier version of your WPF application.

Comment: I have cleaned and rebuild again. It is still same. No update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public ObservableCollection<String> Items { get; set; }

//public 
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    Items.Add("test");

    DataContext = this;
}
```

and change your view

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" Margin="155,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

it's works!

Comment: Hi your example is working. But whenever I try to add my database table name in items, it has an exception like "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll.

Additional information: The specified store provider can not be found in the configuration or invalid."

The code sample is,
  'var eData = new DBEntities();            

            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Items.Add("test");
            Items.Add("adasd");
            Items.Add("adaasdsd");
            Items.Add(Convert.ToString(eData.Table1));'